# "Failed to receive system gesture state notification before next touch"

Tags: ios

I have an app with an app with a `UIScrollView`. I am letting IOS handle all the I/O (i.e., no **`gesture recognizers`**).

I have a cat that likes playing on the `iPad` and she is able to manipulate the `scrollview` in such a way that it gets the error in the title.

I have seen this mentioned in other posts where there were `PinchGestureRecognizer`.

What would be causing this in the absence of one?
What does it mean?

I don't know what the cat does to cause this. She can do it nearly on demand. I can't do it at all.

Comment: That's so cute :-)

Comment: You had me at "I have a cat that likes playing on the iPad" 

Answer (score 9):

Switch off **`Multitasking Gestures`**. This can be done in the **Settings panel**.

`iOS 7` adds support for `gestures` which allow you to control audio or consult the calendar. You do not need to add `gesture recognizers` of your own; the OS brings them in all by itself. They also cannot be disabled from within the app.

Now for what I suspect is the reason for the messages: It seems your cat is sending so many touch events to the touch recognizer that it is overloaded. This is in essence what the error message means. It could not process all touch events in a timely manner. After all, a cat has four paws ...

Comment: As a long-time cat owner, the cat is probably just using its two front paws. That being said, cats are lightning fast--definitely faster than 99% of humans--and so I could definitely see the cat overloading the gesture recognizer with it's front paws.

Comment: @kmiklas I guess I'm in the 1%, was just able to reproduce this myself. :D

Comment: The cat also likely touches multiple points on the surface with each paw, given that it uses "all fingers" at once.... That's such a weird problem.

Comment: I'm no cat but I was tripping this dreadful error from UIKit solely entering 6 digit pin on a number pad of my own making. Your workaround switching ogg gestures in multitasking and dock worked. Jaw pops down in amazement. Any way I can rename myself to Antony Quickie Fingers in the profile?

Comment: After switching multitasking gestures back on it no longer reproduces.

Comment: @AntonTropashko Are you sure that you didn't touch the screen at the same time with your palm (or whatever)?

Comment: I might have. 9.7" iPad is a rather large shovel and my numberpad was onnatop. I'll pay closer attention during the day,. stay tuned, though iPad was rebooted after that incommunicado incident so that might play a role too